# Table and column names in dynamic PostgreSQL queries

Tags: postgresql, dynamic

I'm struggling with a stored procedure which heavily uses dynamic queries. Among others I need to store maximum value of an existing column into a variable.
Postgres documents state "if you want to use dynamically determined table or column names, you must insert them into the command string textually". Based on that I've come up with following statement:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT MAX(' || pkColumn::regclass || ') FROM ' ||
tableName::regclass INTO maxValue;
```

Table name seems to be OK, column name triggers error.

What am I doing wrong ?
Pavel

Comment: The reason: columns is not a classes (no records for it in the `pg_class` table) so you can not cast column name to `regclass` type. More about [`pg_class` catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html) and [`regclass` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html)

Comment: Why downvoted: you have 2 (two) answers but not marked any of it as right or no any comments why its wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT MAX(' || pkColumn ||'::regclass) FROM ' || ...
```

`::regclass` is a cast done inside query. You can also skip it, or put " - which in PG works the same. So please try one of:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT MAX(' || pkColumn || ') FROM ' || ...
```

or

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT MAX("' || pkColumn || '") FROM ' || ...
```

All tree should work. If not - just let me know. In that case it is my fault, postgresql simply works.

Comment: Columns is not classes. Column name can not be casted to `regclass` type. So your first query contains the same error as in the question.

Comment: if `pkColumn` is string with column name, then it can be casted to `regclass`.

Comment: `create table foo(bar int); select 'bar'::regclass;` causing error `ERROR:  relation "bar" does not exist` while `select 'foo'::regclass;` works fine. See my comment under the question with links to the documentation.

Comment: Your select is simply wrong. That additional quotes wouldn't be there when you call `execute` as provided in the answer...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Hower your selects wrong also. first `EXECUTE 'SELECT MAX(' || pkColumn ||'::regclass)` uses the **value** of the `pkColumn` and second one `EXECUTE 'SELECT MAX(' || pkColumn || ')` uses the **name** It is confused me so sorry.

Comment: But it seems that @PavelMurnikov does not interesting in our discussion so lets stop it :o)

Comment: looks so - I've assumed that `pkColumn` is varchar / string at pl/pgsql, so it can be concatenated, as strings. Perhaps that is what was left unclear. EOT :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to cast parameters as they are just identifiers. For better control and readability use the function [`format(),`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) e.g.:

```
declare
    pkcolumn text = 'my_column';
    tablename text = 'my_table';

...

execute format('select max(%I) from %I', pkcolumn, tablename)
into maxvalue;
```